# Finding average of numbers against the ID in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, average

Suppose there are two tables, `Customer` and `Limit`.

`Customer` has the following columns:

```
CustomerId (PK)
Name
```

And `Limit` has these columns:

```
LimitId (PK)
Limitvalue
CustomerId (FK)
```

This is my sample data:

**Customer**

```
CustomerId    Name
----------------------
    1         xyz
    2         abc
    3         uio
```

**Limit**

```
LimitValue     CustomerId
-------------------------
  35303000         1
         0         1
         3         1
         0         2
 225140000         2
         3         2
```

Now when I run this query

```
select a.Limitvalue, b.CustomerId 
from limit a
left join Customer b on a.CustomerId = b.CustomerId
```

It will return data like this:

[image: data]

Here first column is limit value and second is customerid. As you can see there are multiple limit values for one customerid. I want to write a query which shows me the avg of all the limit values against their particular Id.

I tried adding the avg function. The left join here should do the work but it is not working. Can anybody help me by producing some sample data similar to this and writing its query so I can understand the concept ? I would be really thankful.

Comment: Could you provide a sandbox on http://sqlfiddle.com for tests ?

Comment: @Blag sorry I am new at this and have never used sqlfiddle.

Comment: @blag Oh so we just needed to add group by clause.

Comment: Yes, you need to be specific on how the DB should work, so you told it to make the average "by grouping on" if you don't the DB try to make the AVG on the full table .

Comment: @Blag stupid me forgot to add avg function. Your query is perfect. Marked it as an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`group by b.CustomerId`

This, no?

> you need to be specific on how the database should work, so you told it to
>   make the average "by grouping on" if you don't the database try to make the
>   AVG on the full table

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/62bce/1)

**MS SQL Server 2017 Schema Setup**:

**[Results](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/62bce/1/0)**:

```
| CustomerId | Name |
|------------|------|
|          1 |  bob |
|          2 | jean |
```

**[Results](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/62bce/1/1)**:

```
| LimitId | Limitvalue | CustomerId |
|---------|------------|------------|
|       1 |          0 |          1 |
|       2 |         10 |          1 |
|       3 |        100 |          2 |
```

**Query 3**:

```
select 
  avg(a.Limitvalue),
  b.CustomerId 
from limit a
left join Customer b 
  on a.CustomerId= b.CustomerId
group by b.CustomerId
```

**[Results](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/62bce/1/2)**:

```
|     | CustomerId |
|-----|------------|
|   5 |          1 |
| 100 |          2 |
```